# Excel: arrange prescription journey based on dates and IDs

Tags: excel

I am trying to arrange patient's journey based on first regimen then second regimen and so on.

However, after sorting data based on date:

[image: arranged data]

I tried using IF formula as follow but it does not work correctly ( it worked for ID with three rows without having A5 in the formula):

```
=IF(AND(A2=A3,A3=A4,A4=A5,(C5-C4<=30),(C4-C3<=30),D3>(C4+30),D2>(C3+30)),B2&", "&B3&", "&B4&", "&B5,
IF(AND(A2=A3,A3=A4,A4=A5,(C4-C3<=30),D2>(C3+30)),B2&", "&B3&", "&B4,
IF(AND(A2=A3,A3=A4,A4=A5,(C4-C3<=30),D2<(C3+30)),B3&", "&B4,
IF(AND(A2=A3,A3=A4,A4=A5,(C4-C3>30),D2<(C3+30)), B3, "N")
```

I need to have similar results as follow:

[image: Intended Results]

Is there any way to have a formula helping to do so, or any other way to have similar results.

Comment: It appears that what you are calling "Journey" I would describe as a list of drugs being used each year.  Is that correct? If so, you could readily obtain your results using Power Query or VBA.  Is either an option?

Comment: @ronrosenfeld You're correct. I'm more familiar with VBA. Can you please provide me with a VBA code or guide me on where to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been working on Power Query code so I will present that first.

*You can adapt the same algorithm to use in VBA, if you prefer. I would probably be using nested dictionaries and/or a class module to accomplish it effectively*

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***M Code***

```
let

//Change next line to reflect your data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Drugs"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"CATEGORY", type text}, 
        {"F.DATE", type date}, {"L.DATE", type date}}),

//Group by ID, then run fnJourney custom function on each subtable to return results
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {
        {"Count", each fnJourney(_)}}),

//Expand results
    #"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count"),
    #"Expanded Count1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Count", "Count", {"Year", "Reg"}),

//Pivot on Year column with no aggregation
    #"Year Headers" = List.Sort(List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Count1", {{"Year", type text}}, "en-US")[Year])),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Count1", {{"Year", type text}}, "en-US"), 
        #"Year Headers", "Year", "Reg"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Pivoted Column", List.Transform(#"Year Headers", each {_, type text})),
    
//Join with original table
    join = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", "ID", #"Changed Type1","ID", "Joined", JoinKind.LeftOuter),

//add shifted ID column to decide if the joined table should be retained or deleted
    #"Shifted ID" = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(join) & {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(join[ID])},
        type table[ID=Int64.Type, CATEGORY=text, F.DATE=date, L.DATE=date, joined=table, shiftedID=Int64.Type]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Shifted ID", "Custom", each if [shiftedID] <> [ID] then [joined] else null, type nullable table),

//Remove shifted and Joined columns
//Then expand the tables in the Custom Column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"joined", "shiftedID"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", #"Year Headers"),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom", List.Transform(#"Year Headers", each {_, type text}))
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

***Custom Function Code**
Create new Blank query and paste code below*

```
//Rename this query fnJourney

(tbl as table) =>
let
    //Source = Drugs,
    Source = tbl,

    Years = {List.Min(List.Transform(Source[F.DATE], each Date.Year(_)))..
            List.Max(List.Transform(Source[L.DATE], each Date.Year(_)))},

    inJourney = List.Generate(
        ()=>[yr=Years{0}, 
                reg=Text.Combine(Table.SelectRows(Source, 
                        each Years{0} >= Date.Year([F.DATE]) 
                            and Years{0} <= Date.Year([L.DATE]))[CATEGORY],", "), 
            idx=0],
        each [idx] < List.Count(Years),
        each [yr=Years{[idx]+1}, 
              reg=Text.Combine(Table.SelectRows(Source, 
                    (r)=>Years{[idx]+1} >= Date.Year(r[F.DATE]) 
                        and Years{[idx]+1} <= Date.Year(r[L.DATE]))[CATEGORY],", "), 

            idx=[idx]+1],
        each Record.FromList({[yr], [reg]},{"Year","Reg"})
    )
in
    inJourney
```

***Before***
[image]

***After***
[image]

Comment: I have no words to thank you enough. Kindly, can I ask one more question, is it possible to deal with each additional medication as new regimen. For example for ID:1, if there is an additional row as follow: category: insulin nph, F.D: 11/18/2017, L.D: 12/12/2020. Can the result be 2017: sitagliptin, 2017: sitagliptin, insulin glargine. And so on.

Comment: @Dudeii You'd need to develop an algorithm that would segregate that entry into a different column and would also not have undesirable effects on other entries.  Perhaps if, in the custom function, you looked at `F.DATE` instead of `Year(F.DATE)` to determine segregation for that first year, but then the results would not be as you show; so I don't know what the algorithm might be.